# UINavigationController hide nav bar for single viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I knew its a duplicate. But still having an issue and even when tried with possibilities didn't work. Hence posting the same to reach a solution. Hope to get help from you guys.

The initial is embedded inside UINavigationController.  For the initial (the landing view) the navigation bar must be hidden. The other views when called from the landing view - must show the navigation bar.

I'm handling the hide & show of navbar in the landing view by overriding the methods of the view as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Hiding the navigationbar hidden for the first page
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

// Even tried animated:NO & animated:animated

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // Showing the navigationbar hidden for the first page
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```

While the app loads initially, the nav bar is in hidden state (as expected & working fine). When coming back to the landing view from the child view controller, the nav bar gets hidden after some seconds - the landing view gets loaded on to the ui screen.

I also tried using the navigationcontroller delegate method in landing view: `navigationController: willShowViewController: animated:`. But unable to reach the solution that i need.

Hence i provided the navigationcontroller delegate in one of my childviewcontroller and checked whether the childcontroller when popped is not in viewcontrollers of the navigationcontroller using if condition. When yes, then i provided the hide option of the navigationbar. but also failed to have the solution.

During surfed, there was a solution to handle with viewanimation. I tried and that too failed.

Again surfed, the solution provided across is to handle the similar issue with viewwillappear & viewwilldisappear. I'm blinked since the way i'm doing is similar to the proposed way. Even then unable to reach a solution.

FYI.. I'm using Xcode 6.3 and deployment target is 6.0 onwards. I'm using storyboard to manage views.

Please help me sort the issue... `App loads is hiding the nav bar in landing page. But when landing page is loaded back from a child view then the nav bar gets hidden only after the landing page loaded on to the ui. I do need to get hidden of the nav bar as like when app loads, when the child view pops and the landing view gets loaded on the top of the controller.`

Comment: i think you are writing the code in ViewWillAppear.. because of it i think the problem happens. because this method get called after viewDidLoad.

Comment: Try to explain question properly and in short.

Comment: @AshokLondhe, last lines briefed after 'Please help me sort the issue...' of the question is my issue.

Comment: Put `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` in `viewWillDisappear:` instead of `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @M.SwornaVidhya have you tried vijeesh answer.

Comment: use `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`

Comment: @AshokLondhe,@BrittoThomas -- I had tried using [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES] -- also it failed..

Comment: @M.SwornaVidhya write it in correct method... k

Comment: @AshokLondhe, correct method means.. kindly let me know where should i write this code. Had try writing in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @M.SwornaVidhya have you checked Vijeesh answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide navigation bar in the second view then don't try to manage in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear because I have faced a lot of problems by trying like that and it also effected the constraints. Just use delegate for navigation controller in appDelegate it is working fine for me.

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;

    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]])
     {
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
        } else {
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful. It prevents many bug especially when you use inside UITabBarController. If you put hide logic inside each VC, NavBar will be hidden incorrectly sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

So, if you are in some view controller:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

More clarifications:

UINavigationController has a property navigationBarHidden, that allows you to hide/show navigation bar for whole nav controller.

Let's look at the next hierarchy:

```
--UINavigationController
----UIViewController1
----UIViewController2
----UIViewController3
```

Each of three UIViewController will have nav bar since they are in UINavigationController. For example, you want to hide bar into the second (actually it doesn't matter in which one), then write into UIViewController2:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   //it hides
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];    // it shows
}
```

Comment: @M.SwornaVidhya Explain clearly what is the exact issue.

Comment: @AshokLondhe, nav bar hides some time after the initial view loaded. I do need it to hide before the initial view gets loaded on to the screen. I had tried as mentioned by _'vijeesh'_ previously that too failed.

Comment: For that i think you need to use NSNotification and call it from ViewDidLoad.

Comment: i just created sample and i can share you that if you want

Comment: @vijeesh, swornavidhya.ios@gmail.com.. kindly share the sample. let me have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the delegate method in your custom `UINavigationController` class:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SomeViewController class]])
    {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

One advantage for putting it in your `UINavigationController` class is that you don't clutter your `UIViewController` class with code

Tested and works.

**UPDATE**

Create a `UINavigationController` subclass: f.e. `MyNavigationController`

In `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import "MyNavigationController.h"

@property (nonatomic) MyNavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then initialise it in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //Probably some more code here

    self.navigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourRootViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then overwrite the delegate method in your custom `UINavigationController` class

I have little to no experience with storyboards so not really sure how to setup a custom `UINavigationController`, but this is how I do it in code.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654583/creating-a-custom-uinavigationcontroller-in-storyboard-isnt-instantiating-the-v) another SO post how to create a custom `UINavigationController` to use with storyboards.

Comment: how you implemented the delegate method in uiviewcontroller class. I'm unable to understand your way.. will you please eloborate.

Comment: You need to create your own UINavigationController subclass and use that in your AppDelegate